# Replace tag value in data.xml file in Karate

Tags: karate

```
    1.Read the data.xml file from feature file.
    
    2.Replace tag value <UID> to random values - **First I have tried to replace with a hard-coded value,but no changes**
    
    3.Go for POST method and get the response
    
    data.xml and Test.feature file snippet is mentioned below -
    
    **1.data.xml**
    
    <Test>
      <First>
         <UID>87abc65</UID>
         <Second>Food</Second>
      </First>
    </Test>
    
    **2.Test.feature**
Explained the replace in below code -
```

Scenario: get output

- def req = read('data.xml')
- replace req

| token    | value   |

| @@UID@@    | '12345' |

- xml req = req

And request req

When method POST

Then status 200

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `set` is better:

```
* set req/Test/First/UID = '12345'
```

Else you haven't understood replace. Please read the docs carefully: https://github.com/intuit/karate#replace